# How to have two relationships to the same table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

How should I define two relationships to the same table? Here's a simple example:

```
Person
 - id
 - name
```

```
Deal
 - id
 - seller_person_id
 - buyer_person_id
 - date
 - amount
```

On the Person model I can have these relationships:

```
 public function deals_seller()
 {
    return $this->hasMany(Deal::class, 'seller_person_id');
 }

 public function deals_buyer()
 {
    return $this->hasMany(Deal::class, 'buyer_person_id');
 }
```

On the Deal model I've tried the inverse:

```
public function seller()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, null, 'seller_person_id');
}

public function buyer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, null, 'buyer_person_id');
}
```

Using tinker, I can get the deals where a Person is a buyer or seller like this:

```
$person = Person::where('id',3)->with('deals_seller')->with('deals_buyer')->get();
```

But, I can't get the inverse:

```
$deals = Deal::where('amount', > , 100)->with('buyer')->with('seller')->get();
```

It doesn't return the buyer or seller with the deal.

How should I set up the relationships so I can retrieve the buyer and seller for an individual deal or a list of deals?

Comment: remove the `null`s, 2nd argument, you are passing to `belongsTo`

Comment: Sidenote, you don't need to chain `->with()` (unless you want to for some reason, readability, preference, etc.); `->with(['deals_seller', 'deals_buyer'])` will do the same thing as `->with('deals_seller')->with('deals_buyer')` (same with `'buyer' and `'seller'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the buyer and seller for an individual deal or a list of deals, you can define two additional relationships on the `Deal` model, each using the `belongsTo` method to relate to the `Person` model:

```
public function seller()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'seller_person_id');
}


public function buyer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'buyer_person_id');
}
```

With these additional relationships, you can retrieve a list of deals with their respective buyer and seller information like this:

```
$deals = Deal::where('amount', '>', 100)->with('buyer', 'seller')->get();
```

This will eager load the `buyer` and `seller` relationships for each `Deal` instance in the resulting collection. You can access the buyer and seller information for each deal like this:

```
foreach ($deals as $deal) {
    echo "Deal ID: " . $deal->id . "\n";
    echo "Seller: " . $deal->seller->name . "\n";
    echo "Buyer: " . $deal->buyer->name . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the Deal model

```
public function seller()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'seller_person_id');
}

public function buyer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'buyer_person_id');
}
```

You set the `$foreign_key` parameter to null .

[Read this](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_belongsTo)

Comment: I got confused because I usually use the standard naming convention and didn't understand how to use these parameters. Thanks for your help!